# Open multiple files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fopen

I have multiple files that I want to open using fopen. The files have a similar pattern, I have tried to use a for loop as follows, but it does not work. Any ideas how to open each file. Thanks in advance.

```
for ii = 0:12
file = fprintf('population_%d.dat', ii); % -----> File names
generations_fid = fopen(file); % Question ???
matrix = {};  
while ~feof(generations_fid)
   generations = cell2mat(textscan(generations_fid, repmat('%f', 1, (3))));
   if isempty(generations)
       fgetl(generations_fid);
   else
       matrix{end+1} = generations; 
   end
end
end
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: Get the following error: `Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.` Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at the docs of [fprintf](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) vs. [sprintf](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

Comment: You should not use `fprintf`but rather higher-level functions such as `num2str`. You can also look for files direktly with `dif`. Next time, please strip your code to the essential. I guess that your `while`-loop is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using `sprintf` to dynamically generate the file name, not `fprintf`.

`file = sprintf('population_%d.dat', ii);`

It's also good practice to open your file with the required permissions. In your case, it looks like you're reading, so you should use

`generations_fid = fopen(file, 'r');`

Comment: Thanks, it does work. But with this code I can only store the data from the last file (.dat). Any ideas how to store the data of all files in an array.

Comment: move `matrix={}` from inside the for loop to outside the for loop.